# Vue doesn't show whole component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'am a newbie to Vue.

I want to put whole page to component besides header and footer

```
Vue.component('main-block', {template: `
<section id="first-block">...</section>
<section id="second-block">...</section>
<section id="third-block">...</section>`})
```

When I write `<main-page></main-page>` inside #app block, it shows only the first section. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the documentation: [A-Single-Root-Element](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element)

You can't have more than one root element in your component.

> **every component must have a single root element**

Which means that you have to wrap your template in a root element, ex. a div element

For instance:

```
Vue.component('main-block', {template: `
<div>
  <section id="first-block">...</section>
  <section id="second-block">...</section>
  <section id="third-block">...</section>
</div>`})
```